# How to get Vertical Scrollbar in Access 2010 on a long form? Seems like a glitch

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, scrollbar, ms-access-forms

I have created a large Access Form that spans the form header, all of the detail section 22" and form footer. When viewing the form it will not allow scrolling.

I have copied elements into a fresh database and a new form with the same results. I can send a zip file with this single form to anyone interested in helping.

Comment: Seems I figured it out. My Form Header Section was too long. Seems once it gets past 10" it disables the scroll bar on my screen as I was trying to use it improperly to extend the length of my form which is limited to just the 22" . Makes sense that the Header section is not designed to be scrolled, but I had some large images with textboxes between them. Just met a limit of Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I figured it out. My Form Header Section was too long. Seems once it gets past 10" it disables the scroll bar on my screen as I was trying to use it improperly to extend the length of my form which is limited to just the 22" . Makes sense that the Header section is not designed to be scrolled, but I had some large images with text boxes between them. Just met a limit of Access

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the `Scroll Bars` property set to `Both` or `Vertical Only` in the Form Properties:

[image]

Comment: I have confirmed that. I was hoping it was something so simple, but I have never seen this before.  I was worried about corruption so I created the new database and form.

Comment: Seems I figured it out.  My Form Header Section was too long.  Seems once it gets past 10" it disables the scroll bar on my screen as I was trying to use it improperly to extend the length of my form which is limited to just the 22" .  Makes sense that the Header section is not designed to be scrolled, but I had some large images with textboxes between them.  Just met a limit of Access.